# Programmatically create a keycloak realm with auth configs/flows/clients

Tags: typescript, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to create a simple realm using a typescript interface. All I need is a name for the realm and the rest should be filled out automatically. The problem that I'm currently facing is that a `realmRepresentation` for some reason doesn't want to take my configuraton for authenticationFlows, authenticationConfigs, clients and the default browserFlow/directGrantFlow. To create a realm first and add the other parts in chronoligical order is too exhausting because I'd need a new jwt from keycloak for the admin user (because the old one doesn't hold the permissions for the newly created realm). I've been debugging this issue with ChatGPT which kept giving me a minimal example for making the above. It now says that it's not possible to make a realm with that configuration.

Please help me in the right direction, this problem is killing me...

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a new JWT for authenticating with the admin user as long as the JWT is valid. I imagine you're using the keycloak admin client library maintained by the keycloak team and would be configuring to authenticate with the `password` grant type. It would be very simple to configure the library to authenticate as the admin user that gets created when keycloak is first started, and you'd be authenticating against the `admin-cli`  client part of the `master` realm. The token you get in return would be valid for all operations against the existing Admin API. For more detailed info and the alternative way of authenticating using the `client_credentials` grant type see [Keycloak admin client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client).

After setting up the client properly every configuration you described that you wish to do can be done programatically.

Alternatively you can look into the [Export and import realms feature](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport) and see if this is something that you can use to serialize and deserialize a realm with its config and clients after filling it out once manually through the admin console.

Comment: Actually, the jwt contains the permissions for everything inside keycloak, including whether or not I am allowed to make changes to a newly created realm. The newly created realm isn't listed in the permissions so keycloak will think of it being unauthorized.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is default keycloak behavior. Could you edit your post with a minimal reproducible example of what you have tried so far and how to obtain the JWT you describe? If you use the `password` grant to authenticate as an admin user you should be able to manage other realms as:
"Users with the `admin` role are superusers and have full access to manage any realm on the server."
[More info](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#global-roles)